# Integration - Definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a definite integral problem where one of my limits is a variable. I am having trouble understanding what to do with it and where to start from here.

I'm supposed to evaluate g(b) where b>2 and is constant and then evaluate g(5).

$$ g(b) =\int_1^b (27\sqrt x+{5\over x^2}-48x^{1.4}+{3\over x})dx$$

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If $a\neq -1$ $$\int x^adx={x^{a+1}\over a+1}$$ If $a=-1$ $$\int x^{-1}dx=\ln x$$

Use this then put the limits

Comment: Where are you getting a from? Sorry, I'm still new to integration.

Comment: @m.daoo $a$ is any real (or complex) number. I am using  it to denote the power of $x$

Comment: Still not understanding that part in my problem

Comment: @m.daoo Which part?

Comment: Any of it. Could you help me with the actually starting the problem? I might start to understand it a bit better

Comment: @m.daoo What do you know of integration? What is $\int x dx$ ?

Comment: I know some partial fractions, substitution, and algebraic manipulation methods.

Comment: @m.daoo You know substitutions, and you don't know how to solve this problem? ARE YOU KIDDING ME?

Comment: I am familiar with it but like I said I am still new to integration :/

Comment: @m.daoo TRY YOURSELF FIRST. Show your workings!